# canonical bundle of the relative spectrum

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

maybe it is a very trivial quetion but: 
suppose we have a smooth projective variety $X$ over $k$ and $\mathcal{A}$ an $\mathcal{O}_X$ algebra. We have the relative spectrum $Spec(Sym(\mathcal{A}))\rightarrow X$.

What is the canonical budle of $Spec(Sym(\mathcal{A}))$ as a $k$ scheme?

Comment: Notice that $Spec(Sym(\mathcal{A}))$ is affine over $X$ and you have to put very tight restrictions to make it finite, i.e. proper, where the theory of the canonical module works.

Comment: Do you really mean $Sym(\mathcal{A})$ or simply $\mathcal{A}$? In the former case, what is the point of taking an algebra and not an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! Here $\mathcal{A}$ is locally free so that we have finite morphism. Furthermore in this case we need the symmetric algebra.

Comment: If $\mathcal{E}$ is a locally free sheaf on $X$, the canonical line bundle of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathrm{Sym}(\mathcal{E}))$ is the pull back of $\omega _X\otimes \det(\mathcal{E})$. Is that what you are asking?